# SQL Server Rounding (CEILING)

Tags: sql-server

I've got this:

```
DECLARE @billsec as int
SET @billsec = 67

DECLARE @_cost as money
SET @_cost = 0.1 + (CEILING((@billsec / 60)) * 0.015) 

print @_cost
```

It's returning 0.12, but I'm expecting 0.13 as I'm trying to round the `@billsec` to the nearest minute.

Thanks

Comment: If you want "nearest" probably you need `round` rather than `ceiling` but either way you need to stop the integer division.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both operands in `@billsec/60` are integers so the result is always truncated first (integer division).

You need to make one or both decimal or float to preserve the decimal part. Otherwise `CEILING` will always be a no-op as you always pass it an exact integer.

Replacing the relevant part of code with the below will solve this

```
CEILING(@billsec/60.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

cast as float...

```
    DECLARE @billsec as int
    SET @billsec = 67
    DECLARE @_cost as money
    SET @_cost = 0.1 + (CEILING((cast (@billsec as float) / 60)) * 0.015) 
    print @_cost
```